# How to get subview from xib parent View

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, xib

I have a xib file with a single UIButton. So basically it's a UIView with a UIButton inside of it. After inflating the xib, how do I get a handle on the UIButton?

Note: My ViewController itself was created with StoryBoard. I just need this additional button as the footer of my UITableView. I want the button centered in the footer. So instead of creating the button programmatically (I wouldn't know how to tell it to center), I create it in a xib as described above.

Comment: Can't you just make an `IBOutlet` to get a reference to the `UIButton`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `MyCustomButton` class that will inherit after `UIView`.

Then you make your `view` in your button `xib` to be the `MyCustomButton` type.

[image]

Then you can make an `IBOutlet` in `MyCustomButton` class to that button.

Now your custom xib is described by a custom class `MyCustomButton` which has a reference to the button.

Read [here](http://www.maytro.com/2014/04/27/building-reusable-views-with-interface-builder-and-auto-layout.html) in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called top-level objects, you can access them using below code.

```
NSNib *nib = [[[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MyView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
NSArray *topLevelObjects;
if (! [nib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&topLevelObjects]) // error

MyView *myView = nil;
for (id topLevelObject in topLevelObjects) {
if ([topLevelObject isKindOfClass:[MyView class]) {
    mySelectedView = topLevelObject;
    break;
    }
}
```

In the if statement select the proper class you want to get handle and you will get that object in "mySelectedView".